Need to call trivial destructor in standard compliant containers
I'm implementing my own version of standard-compliant containers. I read the following. It states that elements should be destroyed using the allocator destroy. Does it suggest a container must call the destructor of elements, even if it is trivial? My interpretation is we should first have the need to call the destructor. If so, we must use the allocator destroy. Otherwise, we don't need to call allocator destroy either. Under this interpretation, we can skip calling allocator destroy for elements with a trivial destructor. This can lead to optimization in sequence containers.
From cpp20 standard:

For the components aﬀected by this subclause that declare an
allocator_type, objects stored in these components shall be
constructed using the function
allocator_traits<allocator_type>::rebind_traits<U>::construct and
destroyed using the function
allocator_traits<allocator_type>::rebind_traits<U>::destroy
(20.10.9.2), where U is either allocator_type::value_type or an
internal type used by the container.


I expected compiler to remove loop of noop. So I won't bother to manually try to write this possible optimization.

Thanks Jarod42. With custom allocator, destroy may do something else like logging/counting. This certainly can't be optimized away. The question is if I need to call it in the first place

Couldn't you utilize std::is_trivially_copyable to (not) execute calls to destroy elements?

If it does logging/counting and you don't call it, the user won't get logging/counting, or worse, get wrong logging/counting. Do you really want that?

To @n.m.couldbeanAI m, if a call to destructor is not needed in the first place, then not calling the logging/counting is correct. For example, if one wants to count the number of times vector<int, counting_allocator<int> > destroys int. I don't see any inconsistency if the counter is always zero.

Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. You may read the title before I did the edit. This is about skipping calls to destructor/destroy, not about constructing objects.

Whether the container should call the destructor from the usability/best practice aspect is one question, and whether it is standard conformant is another. The question seems to be asking the latter while the comments address the former.

If the container class allows the use of a custom allocator, the you must use the "allocator destroy" as you have no idea how the allocator works internally - book keeping, raw memory book keeping etc.

Perhaps the allocator keeps track of the number of live objects, or the amount of memory they occupy. Why throw it off if you don't need to? If the user wants fast allocation, they will use a fast allocator such that destroy() can be optimized away. If they want something else, why deny them what they want?

"For example, if one wants to count the number of times vector<int, counting_allocator > destroys int" Nope, this doesn't make sense. This isn't up to you to decide, rather the custom allocator should decide if it wants this or not.

Thanks @RichardCritten. From a standard compliance perspective, it is generally allowed to skip calling trivial destructor. If the need to call "allocator destroy" stems from the need to call destructor, we can therefore also skip calling "allocator destroy". Is there anywhere in the standard that contradicts this logic?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I think that is a fair point from the usability perspective. I should give users a maximum freedom. Echoing Weijun's comment, this question is more about standard compliance though. I want to know how much freedom I have in implementing this logic without breaking rules in standard.

If the question is "how can I be maximally evil without breaking the letter of the law", then I refuse to answer it.

@n.m.couldbeanAI that's no problem. Thanks for your previous responses. Looks like the general attitude I got is to use the standard as the minimum requirement and provide maximum freedom to the users. And then consider optimization on top of that.

A note on the name. Yes it is, but not nearly as hard as many make it out to be by using too much C. The real hard part about C++ is the breadth of the language. It takes longer  for mere mortals to swallow than most languages.

@user4581301 Yeah that's why I took this user name. Just template worths a 700 page book alone. However it is so much fun to explore.

The allocator has construct method too. It can be used to change the behavior of construction. As such, it must be paired by a proper destroy function. Consider the construct/destroy pair as allocator-specific extra init/finish on the object. Without them you will lose control over the elements. Moreover, as of C++17, most std containers must satisfy AllocatorAwareContainer conditions, which makes them PIMPL-applicable. Your proposed optimization forces compile failure on incomplete types; because compiler cannot decide whether or not incomplete types satisfy any preconditions.

@Red.Wave Thanks. Could you point me to the reference of "which makes them PIMPL-applicable. Your proposed optimization forces compile failure on incomplete types"? I did some research and cpp containers are not supposed to work with incomplete types.

This is a reference for vector: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector which clearly states since C++17, element type can be incomplete. And this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer shows minimum allocator requirements for vector and most containers. Only  the map family cannot work with incomplete key or value types. Define essential members of custom allocator in the same TU as Owner class, and you can PIMPL std::vector.

Based on the discussion, there is no clear answer to whether skipping allocator destroy for trivially destructible types is allowed by the standard. However people tend to prefer the implementation of calling it regardless and let the compiler take care of potential optimization. I will mark this question as closed.
